# How can I restrict a time input value?

Tags: html

I want to display an input type hour from 08:00 to 20:00. I tried this:

```html
<input type="time" id="timeAppointment" name = "timeAppointment" min="08:00" max="20:00" placeholder="hour"  required/>
```

But when I display it I can still select any time, it does not restrict me as I indicate. What is the problem? If is necessary some code I work with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints within the input do not prevent from entering an incorrect value in this case. Here is an overview of what MDN says in their [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#validation):

> By default,  does not apply any validation to entered values, other than the user agent's interface generally not allowing you to enter anything other than a time value.

But you can write validations with JavaScript, or visual validations with CSS, like so:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  gap:1rem;
}

input:invalid+span:after {
  content: '✖';
}

input:valid+span:after {
  content: '✓';
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <input type="time" id="timeAppointment" name = "timeAppointment" value="08:00" min="08:00" max="20:00" placeholder="hour" required/>
  <span class="validity"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `min` and `max` properties in `input` tags do not inherently prevent you from accepting out of range values as inputs, but it controls the `valid` property of the tag, which can then be used such as in css to style your page accordingly. Some browsers do make it so that you cannot input out of the specified range, but it is not platform-independent behaviour.

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#setting_maximum_and_minimum_times

If you want to ensure that only the time between `min` and `max` are input, you could programmatically implement that using an `onchange` listener on your `input` element as follows:

Make sure to indicate to the user why their input is not changing (because it is not between `min` and `max`) using css and text, etc.

```js
const timeInput = document.getElementById("timeAppointment");
timeInput.value = '15:56';

let previousValue = timeInput.value;

timeInput.onchange = () => {
  console.log(previousValue)
  console.log(timeInput.value)
  
  if (timeInput.value < timeInput.min || timeInput.value > timeInput.max) {
    timeInput.value = previousValue;
  }
  
  previousValue = timeInput.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="timeAppointment" name="timeAppointment" min="08:00" max="20:00" required/>
```

However, there is a caveat to this. Imagine you are changing your time from `02:00PM` to `11:00AM`. You would go from left to right, and as soon as you change `02` hours to `11` hours, the javascript validation fails as it becomes `11:00PM` and the value is not able to update.

Either you will have to write a convoluted way to get around all the edge cases, or the users will have to find a weird way to change their time. This is why this is generally a bad idea to validate on every input like this, and instead you can validate it when you submit the form, or `onfocusout` and let the user know by appropriate styling.

Answer (score 0):

`min`, `max` attributes does not disable input range values.

This is how I implemented time range restriction with some jquery

```html
<input type="time" min="08:00" max="19:00"class="js-restrict-time">

<script>
$(".js-restrict-time").change(e => {
    let target = $(e.target)
    const minTime = target.attr('min')
    const maxTime = target.attr('max')
    let time = e.target.value

    if (Date.parse(time) < Date.parse(minTime))
        target.val(minTime)
    if (Date.parse(time) > Date.parse(maxTime))
        target.val(maxTime)
})
</script>
```

> Libraries Used: jQuery 3.6, [DateJs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)